# How to place two divs side by side when having a sidebar

Tags: html, css

When I place two different divs side by side with a sidebar, and have only margin to the right on the first one (that is on the left). And the right one don't have one.

How do I create a good structure so I don't have to manually add `style="margin:0"` to the right HTML element?

To demonstrate this I have created this illustration:

[image: illustration]

Comment: Links to images are useless! [ask]

Comment: why don't you use bootstrap, foundation or any other grid systems?

Comment: I don't have the ability to show you all the source code at the moment, that's why.

Comment: There is no way to detect from code which div happens to appear on the right.  what you can do instead of using a style tag is make a class specifically for a margin of zero like mr0

Comment: you can use `:last` filter if there are a bunch and you just want to detect the last one , but in your case that is not going to work

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I edited your question to remove non-constructive comments from the question body. I also included the image itself in the body - please see the editing help for more information on formatting. Please edit the question and provide any additional details such as code sample that may be necessary to identify the specific problem. Good luck!

Comment: The comment by Ahmet Cetin is your best starting point.  They have addressed those issues.  However, your question lacks a major input: are you trying to be responsive to the browser's viewport? In other words, if your window tightens, what do you expect to happen to the two divs: will they stack of must they stay side-by-side? if it is the latter case, inspect this page!

Comment: Some code or a JSFiddle would be the best to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `nth-child(odd)` to target every odd item in the order of your items.

Since you didn't provide any actual code example, I have put together a structure I felt appropriate for such a design.

Here's an example I knocked up: http://codepen.io/michaelpumo/pen/OMgEKp

In the CodePen, I am using Jade for HTML and SCSS for the CSS. I recommend using them, but if you want the compiled code, it's below.

**HTML**

```
<div class="grid">
  <div class="grid__left">
    <div class="grid__hero"></div>
    <div class="grid__item"></div>
    <div class="grid__item"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="grid__right">
    <div class="grid__sidebar"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  padding-top: 10px;
}

.grid {
  width: 600px;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.grid__left, .grid__right {
  float: left;
}
.grid__left {
  width: 400px;
}
.grid__right {
  width: 200px;
  padding-left: 10px;
}
.grid__hero, .grid__item, .grid__sidebar {
  background: #000;
}
.grid__hero {
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 0 0 10px 0;
}
.grid__hero {
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 0 0 10px 0;
}
.grid__item {
  float: left;
  clear: none;
  width: 195px;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 0 10px 10px 0;
}
.grid__item:nth-child(odd) {
  margin-right: 0;
}
.grid__sidebar {
  width: 100%;
  height: 410px;
}
```

Hope it makes sense. The real meat of the matter is on the `.grid__item` divs, that have a margin right, but this being removed for every odd one, which results in the effect I think you're after.

In any case, it looks like you're after a grid system. There are many out there; most popular being Bootstrap. I strongly recommend using one of them: http://getbootstrap.com

Personally, I use a SCSS based grid called Neat: http://neat.bourbon.io/